# Electron exe doesn't launch when not connected to internet: windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron, electron-packager

I have an electron application, packaged for Windows through electron-packager, when I try to open the exe with out internet connection, the application is not launching. 
With internet connection it's working perfectly fine.
I googled but not of much help.

Any insights would be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Try to check if your app crash when an HTTP request throw an error?

Comment: To start debugging, try by running the application in a development enviorment (using electron command from command line) while you aren't connected to internet and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you @Radar155, how silly was i, uuuhhhh!! Figured out , i was calling app.quit() when no internet.